# Dom manipulator using parse5 (querySelector) - Node.JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, html-parsing, cheerio, jsdom

Parse5 seems to be a solid parser, is there a native implementation of the web DOM manipulation functionality built on top of it for Node.JS?

**What do I need:**

- querySelector & querySelectorAll
- insertAdjacentHTML
- getAttribute
- removeAttribute
- replaceWith
- childNodes
- tagName

**Why I'm not using:**

- **JSDom** can't handle self-closing elements (no xHTML)
- **node-html-parser** can't handle comments (only allows to read existing)
- **cheerio** uses jQuery syntax